# How do I convert an SVG to PDF in C#?

Tags: c#, abcpdf, abcpdf9

How can I set a cookie at ABCpdf12 in this code?

```
string url = "";

Doc theDoc = new Doc();
theDoc.Read(url);
theDoc.Save("document.pdf");
theDoc.Clear();
```

Big thanks!

Comment: What's not working in your code? Where do you think it's setting the cookie?

Comment: The website only displays the correct content if a special cookie is set.

Comment: @JakobOfner your code shows nothing relevant though - no HTTP calls or attempts to set a cookie. `Doc` could be anything

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Doc is from the WebSupergoo.ABCpdf12 NuGet-packet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already solved the problem.
I downloaded the svg with selenium and used iText7 to generate the PDF-file.

I used *itext7*, which I've installed as NuGet-packet.

```
using iText;
using iText.Svg.Converter;
```

and here the code:

```
FileStream svgPath = File.Open("input.svg", FileMode.Open);
FileStream pdfPath = File.Create("output.pdf");
SvgConverter.CreatePdf(svgPath, pdfPath);
```

To avoid errors, you should set the current location equal to the location of the svg file. (*Directory.SetCurrentDirectory()*)